# How do I find all tables in a DB that have no explicit primary key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, primary-key

A Google search spewed forth millions of hits on how to find tables without clustered indexed, the PK normally being the clustered index of a table. However, a table could easily have a natural key as a clustered index, and a non-clustered surrogate index, like an identity column.

How do I find all tables in a DB without a primary key defined? I have 245 tables in this DB: manual inspection is grossly inefficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Couple ways to skin this cat but this works fine in SQL Server 2005 and up, and I find it a pain free way to handle the problem -

The `OBJECTPROPERTY()` function can list various properties about objects - like tables. One of those properties is whether or not a table has a primary key.

`OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, tablehasprimarykey)` = 0 would be a table without a primary key.

So

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME( object_id ) as SchemaName, name AS TableName
FROM sys.tables
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id,'tablehasprimaryKey') = 0 
ORDER BY SchemaName, TableName ;
```

Should give you what you need. You can see all about the other ways to use the OBJECTPROPERTY() function in books online. This is the [2012 version of the article.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx)

Comment: well the object_id will work I thought we are using the function.but the `sys.tables` itself gives the id and thanks for showing this wonderful function.

Comment: No problem. It is a good function to have. Lot of properties. In this case you have it right - sys.tables already lists the object_id inside of it. and that is the object_id we want to pass in for the ID parameter to the OBJECTPROPERTY function. Thanks for the good catch on the reserved keyword I used there :)

Comment: ,you were precisely correct about the object_id function, I just mixed things up there.well thanks for pointing it out.well the `objectproperty()` is available from 2005 onwards,I just checked bol,right?

Comment: Yes. There in 2005 - 2014 and beyond at this point :-)

Comment: I edited the script to add Schema Name. Note that (like OBJECTPROPERTY) the OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME() function was new to MSSQL 2005.

Comment: A fair edit @GreenstoneWalker - I approved it. OP didn't ask for schema, but nothing wrong with showing the schema at all. Good call :-)

Comment: Something also worth noting - this query can be run against multiple servers by means of the [Central Management Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895144.aspx) feature.

Comment: Well sort of :-) Yes it can, but the query as written is for one database so you'd have to run this in a loop through databases, since sys.tables belongs to a database.

Answer (score 5):

Mike's solution is excellent for the specific problem.

If you want more flexibility, here's an alternative that can be easily morphed into a query that returns other information, such as finding all tables that are heaps, or finding tables that have no unique constraints *at all*.

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id) AS SchemaName,
    t.name AS TableName
    FROM sys.tables t
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
                FROM sys.indexes i
                WHERE
                    (i.object_id = t.object_id) AND
                    (i.is_primary_key = 1)
        );
```

Once your (sub)system goes over ~50 tables, it's really important to get familiar with all the metadata tables, because as you said, going through each table manually is impractical (and prone to error!).

Comment: +1 for "because as you said, going through each table manually is impractical (and prone to error!)." Amen there. Very prone to error :)

Answer (score 4):

The [Policy Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510667.aspx) feature of SQL Server can do some of this.

The Table facet has fields @HasIndex and @HasClusteredIndex (as well as other ones that may be useful, like triggers). A policy can be created to check conditions on all tables, in all databases, in a number of servers (using the Central Management Server feature).

It can't, however, check the existence of a primary key index or constraint. I would have sworn that there was a field @HasPrimaryKey but it's not there in MSSQL2012. I'm either misremembering or going mad.

Note: Policy Management is included with SQL Server 2012 Enterprise, Business Intelligence and Standard editions. It is not available in Express edition.

Comment: I think you could write a custom condition that checks this. +1 for a totally different way to do this.